# (XML) Getting an element if a node has the given value

Tags: python, python-3.x, xml, element, elementtree

So I have an XML file.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<plist version="1.0" gjver="2.0">
    <dict>
        <k>LLM_01</k>
        <d>
            <k>_isArr</k>
            <t/>
            <k>k_0</k>
            <d>
                <k>kCEK</k>
                <i>4</i>
                <k>k18</k>
                <i>18</i>
                <k>k36</k>
                <i>40</i>
                <k>k2</k>
                <s>Run</s>
            </d>
            <k>k_1</k>
            <d>
                <k>kCEK</k>
                <i>4</i>
                <k>k18</k>
                <i>18</i>
                <k>k36</k>
                <i>40</i>
                <k>k2</k>
                <s>Run2</s>
            </d>
        </d>
        <k>LLM_02</k>
        <i>35</i>
    </dict>
</plist>
```

My goal is to get every element which have the value "Run", for the key "k2".

So at first, I though about some sort of for loop :

```
    root = ET.parse("This file.xml").getroot()
    ELEMENTS = root.find('LLM_01')
    for element in ELEMENTS:
        "some code here"
```

The problem is, I don't even know what to put inside the "some code here" section. I was thinking about making a dictionnary with all the keys and value like so:

```
k_0 = {'kCEK' : 4, 'k18' : 18, 'k36' : 40, 'k2' : 'Run'}
k_1 = {'kCEK' : 4, 'k18' : 18, 'k36' : 40, 'k2' : 'Run2'}
```

But I don't know how I could do that.
So my problem is : How to check if, inside an element, the key "k2" has the value "Run" ?
and if so, getting the element inside a variable ?

I know this could either easy or difficult, but I really don't have an idea on how to do that. Your help would really be needed, and if so, thanks in advance !

(If you need more explenation, let me know.)

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this can be done with elementtree, but it can be done with lxml:

```
from lxml import etree
llm = """[your xml above]"""
doc = etree.XML(llm.encode())

#next line will have to modified as a function of the number of dictionaries
d_dict = {'k_0': {},'k_1': {}}
for d in (d_dict.items()):
    targets = doc.xpath('.//d/k[1]/following-sibling::d')
    for d,t in zip(d_dict.values(),targets):
      for k,v in zip(t.xpath('./k/text()'),t.xpath('./*[not(name()="k")]/text()')):
        d[k]=v
d_dict
```

Output:

```
{'k_0': {'kCEK': '4', 'k18': '18', 'k36': '40', 'k2': 'Run'},
 'k_1': {'kCEK': '4', 'k18': '18', 'k36': '40', 'k2': 'Run2'}}
```